# taglib-sharp not tagging mkv files

Tags: c#, tagging, mkv, taglib-sharp, matroska

I'm using taglib-sharp to write tags to video files. It's able to write tags just fine to mp4 files, but I can't get it to write tags to mkv files. I've tried various applications to view the metadata, but none of them can see any, including MediaInfo.

Do I need to do something different to tag mkv files? They're definitely supported as there's code specifically for tagging them, but I can't find anything suggesting I'm doing something wrong.

I'm tagging files like so:

```
TagLib.File file = TagLib.File.Create(row.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
file.Tag.Album = series.SeriesName;
file.Tag.Disc = (uint)episodeData.Season;
file.Tag.Track = (uint)episodeData.Episode;
file.Tag.Title = foundEpisode.EpisodeName;
file.Tag.Comment = foundEpisode.Overview;
file.Tag.Genres = new string[] { "TVShows" };
```

I'm using the latest version of taglib-sharp too (2.1.0). Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you calling `file.Save()`?

Comment: Yes, I am. There's a big chunk of code after this for downloading images, so I didn't include the whole thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone encountering the same issue, the cause is the outdated version (6 years out of date!) of taglib-sharp in the NuGet package manager. Build from source and Matroska files seem to tag just fine.